# onDrop event not working properly React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this `dropZone` that is clickable and opens up the file selecting thing. And once a file is selected from your computer it gives a preview of it (if it's an image). I would like to be able to drag and drop the same file and it do the same thing as if I were to click in the div and open up a file.

I tried calling my `handleChange` function inside of the `onDrop` but it didn't quite work and I would get an `TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined` error or it just wouldn't do anything at all. [Here is a CodeSandbox of the dropzone component on it's own.](https://codesandbox.io/s/232k3xq2kj)

Here's that snippet of my code:

```
class DropZone extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      file: "",
      fileId: uuid(),
      className: 'dropZone'
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this._onDragEnter = this._onDragEnter.bind(this);
    this._onDragLeave = this._onDragLeave.bind(this);
    this._onDragOver = this._onDragOver.bind(this);
    this._onDrop = this._onDrop.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
    })
    console.log("handleChange")
    //document.getElementsByClassName("dropZone").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.state.file + ')';
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', this._onDragLeave);
    window.addEventListener('dragenter', this._onDragEnter);
    window.addEventListener('dragover', this._onDragOver);
    document.getElementById('dragbox').addEventListener('dragleave', this._onDragLeave);
    window.addEventListener('drop', this._onDrop);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this._onDragLeave);
    window.removeEventListener('dragenter', this._onDragEnter);
    window.addEventListener('dragover', this._onDragOver);
    document.getElementById('dragbox').removeEventListener('dragleave', this._onDragLeave);
    window.removeEventListener('drop', this._onDrop);
  }

  _onDragEnter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  _onDragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }

  _onDragLeave(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  _onDrop(e, event) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.handleChange
    let files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log('Files dropped: ', files);
    // Upload files
    //this.handleChange.bind(this)
    console.log(this.state.file)
    return false;
  }

render() {
  const uniqueId = this.state.fileId;
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" id={uniqueId} name={uniqueId} class="inputFile" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      <label   htmlFor={uniqueId} value={this.state.file}>
      {this.props.children}
        <div className="dropZone" id="dragbox" onChange={this.handleChange}>
          Drop or Choose File
          <img src={this.state.file} id="pic" name="file" accept="image/*"/>
        </div>
      </label>
      <div>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

There's going to be multiple of these that upload their own individual photo/file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to pass on the `e` parameter to `handleChange()` and correctly grab the files from the event.

**onDrop**

```
_onDrop(e, event) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.handleChange(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
    let files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log("Files dropped: ", files);
    // Upload files
    console.log(this.state.file);
    return false;
}
```

**handleChange**

```
handleChange(file = "") {
    this.setState({
      file: URL.createObjectURL(file)
    });
    //document.getElementsByClassName("dropZone").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.state.file + ')';
}
```

And in `render` do parsing of the event to get the file:
`onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.files[0])}`

Alternatively, you could make two handleChange to clean mess up your `render` method.

Link to working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/7k6y94k6w6 (based on your code)

Comment: Yay! The dropping part works but now when I click in the div to add a file I get this error `TypeError
Cannot read property 'files' of undefined`

Comment: I think it is because I have something named "files" already in my `handleChnage` function/method, But I am not entirely sure

Comment: My bad. I have updated the example so that `handleChange` takes the file as the parameter. Changed accordingly in `render` (`<input` component) and `_onDrop`.